# How i can do like this? Send request to webpack, if response was 404, then request to webpack "/inidex.html":?

Tags: nginx, webpack-dev-server, nginx-reverse-proxy

How i can do like this? Send request to webpack, if response was 404, then request to webpack "/inidex.html":

```
server {
  listen 80;
  
  location @webpack_dev_server {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location / {
    try_files @webpack_dev_server @webpack_dev_server/index.html =404;
  }
}
```

How to configure webpack historyApiFallback I know, the question is how to configure nginx to check for the existence of a "file" on another server =)

How i can check "if another server return 404, then try request to another server `another_server/index.html`? its possible with nginx?

Comment: You can't use `try_files`. You could try `location / { proxy_intercept_errors on; error_page 404 = /index.html; proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; ... }`

Comment: @Richard Smith how i can check "if another server return 404, then try request to another server `another_server/index.html`? its possible?